# How to display two variables in a .liquid file?

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

I am trying to replace

```
<form action="{{ form_action }}" data-productid="{{product.id}}" method="{{form_method}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="{{form_id}}" data-section="{{ section.id }}" class="product-form-{{ section.id }} {{form_class}}">
```

with

```
{% form 'product', product, data-productid: product.id, id: form_id, data-section: section.id, class: "product-form-{{ section.id }} {{form_class}}" %}
```

Everythink is great, except:

```
class: "product-form-{{ section.id }} {{form_class}}"
```

I have no idea how to display "section.id" and "form_class" as a variable, but not as a text.

I was trying to display as in PHP ("product-form-" . section.id . " " . form_class) and as in Javascript ("product-form-" + section.id + " " + form_class) but it return an error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split your logic a little.

First set the classes in a variable and call that one instead.

```
{%- capture classes -%}
  product-form-{{ section.id }} {{form_class}}
{%- endcapture -%}

{% form 
  'product', 
  product, 
  data-productid: product.id, 
  id: form_id, 
  data-section: section.id, 
  class: classes 
%}
```